# Load data from Firebase to ExpandableList

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, expandablelistview

I'm trying to use expandable list in my app. I'm following these 
[steps](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/), but I'm stuck in how to retrieve the data from Firebase to add them as Dummydata to my code.

here is the **main Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ExpandableListAdapter myAdapter;
ExpandableListView myList;
List<String> listDataHeader;
HashMap<String,List<String>> listDataChild;

private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
private DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference;
private ChildEventListener mChildEventListener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // get the listview
    myList=(ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.Explist);
    prepareListData();
    myAdapter= new ExpandableListAdapter(this,listDataHeader,listDataChild);
    myList.setAdapter(myAdapter);

}
private void prepareListData(){
    mFirebaseDatabase= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    mDatabaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("category");
    //Read Data from Database
    mChildEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
            listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
            listDataHeader=dataSnapshot.getValue();
            /*
            * how to load data from firebase to the expandable
            * 
            * 
            * */

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    };
    mDatabaseReference.addChildEventListener(mChildEventListener);

}
```

here is the code for the adapter

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
private Context _context;
private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
// child data in format of header title, child title
private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader, HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild) {
    this._context = context;
    this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
    this._listDataChild = listDataChild;

}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return this._listDataHeader.size();
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition) ;
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_gruop, null);
    }
    TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
    lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    if(convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    }
    TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

    txtListChild.setText(childText);
    return convertView;}


@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Add method in the Adapter for updating the list and adding item in your list

```
      public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter
        {
            private Context _context;
            private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
            // child data in format of header title, child title
            private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

            public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader, HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild) {
                this._context = context;
                this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
                this._listDataChild = listDataChild;

            }

    public void addItemToList(String newItem){
       this._listDataChild.plus(newItem);
       notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void setList(List<String> newList){
        this._listDataChild = listDataChild;
        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
            ...
```

And use these functions in the Activity class,,
(its in kotlin.. Convert it to Java in AS )

```
/*
            * how to load data from firebase to the expandable
            * 
            * 
            * */
           if (dataSnapshot != null) {
                    val newList = arrayListOf<String>()

                    for (listDataSnap in dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        val newItem: String? = listDataSnap.getValue()
                        if (newItem != null) {
                                newList.add(newItem)
                        }
                    }

                    myAdapter?.setList(newList)

                }
```

*The point is to get the idea! Cheers

Comment: thank you..but i don't get this point you refer to" DataListHeader" by newItem and "DataListChild" by newList am I right? @SijanGurung

Comment: I'm sorry but I have to define the header to string and the child to list of string instead of what i define it above right?  @SijanGurung